# Is it possible to play an audio file using the absolute path in react-native?

Tags: audio, react-native

I am using react-native-audio-android and I want to have a playback before I upload the audio I recorded, but the audio recorded is only saving to the phone and it is just returning the absolute path like `/storage/emulated/0/AUDIO_:20180403_151649.3gp`.

Comment: Have you tried this one? `https://github.com/futurice/react-native-audio-toolkit`. It's a recorder/playback library

Comment: try accessing the file with file:///storage/emulated/0/AUDIO_:20180403_151649.3gp

Comment: @renren would you please share how you made it work? I'm having the same problem trying to play an audio on Android with react-native-sound